# How to get the id of the object in the view from the context?

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models: 'Portfolio' and 'Screenshots'. 'Screenshots' has field 'project' - it's foreign key to 'Portfolio'. And I have view 'ProjectDetailView'. I added 'Screenshots' model via get_context_data().
How to get by filter only objects 'Screenshots' model where

```
context['screenshots'] = Screenshot.objects.filter(project=???) # id from Project object
```

My code is below.
This my model Portfolio:

```
class Project(BaseModel):
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name='URL', unique=True, blank=False)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Category')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Title', blank=False)
    publication = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Publication', default=True)
```

And my model Screenshots:

```
class Screenshot(BaseModel):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/projects/%Y/%m/', verbose_name='Image', blank=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is view.py:

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'portfolio/project_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'project'
    queryset = Project.objects.filter(publication=True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['screenshots'] = Screenshot.objects.filter(project=???) # id from Project object
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['screenshots'] = Screenshot.objects.filter(project=self.object) 
    return context
```

And you can also pass in the properties of the instance as screenshot_set